# Implementing functions in another class

Tags: android, class, implementation, gesture

I am having trouble with this function I created: `enter(linearLayout, llp)`. I created it in my class `Game` but am trying to implement it in my class `MyTouchListener`.

And as you can see below, I made class `MyTouchListener` extend class `Game` so it can get the functions of that class, including `enter(linearLayout, llp)`

Currently the `enter(linearLayout, llp)` is in the `onFling` method in class `MyTouchListener` but it does not work. My app crashes when I fling across the screen.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here and offer a solution?

class `MyTouchListener`:

```
public class MyTouchListener extends Game implements OnTouchListener{

    protected static final String TAG = "MyTouchListener";
    protected static final boolean D = true;

    public interface MyListener{
        public void onTouch();
    }

    private MyListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private class MyClickListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (D){
                enter(linearLayout, llp); //ERROR HERE
                Log.d(TAG, "2 - onFling event");

            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public MyTouchListener(Context context, MyListener listener){
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyClickListener());
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (D){
            Log.d(TAG, "2 - onTouch event");
        }
        mListener.onTouch();
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

class `Game`:

```
public class Game extends Activity   {

    protected static LinearLayout linearLayout;
    protected static LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp; 

    public void enter(String[] w, LinearLayout ll, LinearLayout.LayoutParams params){

    ...//code
    ...//code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

        mListener = new MyListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTouch() {
                if (D){
                    Log.d(TAG, "2 - onTouch event");
                }
            }
        };

        for(Button b:button_list){
            b.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), mListener));
        }

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_bttn_words);

        llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        llp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    }
```

Here is the error log. This occurs once I fling across the screen:

```
12-14 20:09:28.342: D/MyTouchListener(18212): 2 - onTouch event
12-14 20:09:28.342: D/MyTouchListener(18212): 2 - onTouch event
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/InputEventReceiver(18212): Exception dispatching input event.
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:1405)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7456)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2186)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1516)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2134)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7641)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3676)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3607)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4802)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4781)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4873)
12-14 20:09:28.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18212):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:1405)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7456)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2186)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1516)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2134)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7641)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3676)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3607)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4802)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4781)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4873)
12-14 20:09:28.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
```

I tried tons of things including creating constructors for my `Game` class and apply it to my other class but that didn't work. So I thought the best strategy would be to make class `MyTouchListener` extend class `Game` and make the global variables static.

Comment: `offer a solution` - to what?

Comment: that this line of code: enter(linearLayout, llp) does not work. I edited the post to better explain the issue. Let me know if you have other questions

Comment: Please stop and think about this.  All we know is what you have written in the question, no more.  What does `does not work` mean?

Comment: Good point. I will post the error log. I am actually not sure what the error and why the app keeps crashing

Comment: the post is edited again. I explain the problem, show the error log, and tell of various attempts to solve the issue. I hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't embed an image, it's very hard to read.  Please copy and paste the stack trace. You also have not included the entire stack trace.  The key information is missing.

Comment: Hopefully this will be the last time I need to edit. Does my post now have all the information you need?

Comment: I figured it out. I just needed to make more variables static... Thanks for your help though